# Change order of blocks via local.xml file

Tags: magento, block

Is it possible to change the order of already existing blocks via the local.xml file?
I know you can change the order of a block with the after or before attribute, but how can one change those attributes of existing blocks.

For example, if I want to place the layered navigation block underneath the newsletter subscription block in the left column, how would I do that?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to perform a small trick, remove child block and add it in new position:

```
<reference name="parent.block.name">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>child_block_alias</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>child.block.name</blockName>
        <siblingName>name_of_block</siblingName>
        <after>1</after>
        <alias>child_block_alias</alias>
    </action>
</reference>
```

This Layout XML instruction does what you want. Look at this short reference of parameters for `insert` method:

- `blockName` is your block unique name across the layout, `product.view` for example
- `siblingName` is an block unique name, that is already exists in insertion target block, used for positioning of your block. Leave empty to display it at the top or at the bottom.
- `after` is a boolean identifier of block position. If equals to `1`, then the block will be added after `siblingName` or in the bottom of the children list if `siblingName` is empty
- `alias` is the alias of your block, if it is empty the name of block will be used.

Some Examples:

**Move cart sidebar block after recently viewed products**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
        <siblingName>right.reports.product.viewed</siblingName>
        <after>1</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Move cart sidebar block before recently viewed products**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
        <siblingName>right.reports.product.viewed</siblingName>
        <after>0</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Move cart sidebar block at the end of the right block**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
        <siblingName></siblingName>
        <after>1</after>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Move cart sidebar block at the top of the left block**

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <alias>cart_sidebar</alias>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <action method="insert">
        <blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Enjoy working with Magento!

Comment: Although I'm aware that the name of the action arguments are irrelevant, you've used s/subling/sibling/g throughout :)

Comment: @Nick, yes, only the order of the arguments are important, the name of arguments is not used in method call.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing this tutorial. But I have a beginner question.
How can I get the complete list of blocks?

Comment: @Denys: That deserves to be a question of it's own. Page use the Ask Question at the top of the page.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove previous layered navigation block and add a new layered navigation block after newsletter block.

```
<reference name="left">
 <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
 <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnavcustom" after="left.newsletter" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Note that I use a custom name for the new block.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (EE1.14) but something close to it, this:

```
<wishlist_index_index>
    <reference name="customer.wishlist.items">
        <action method="unsetChild">
             <name>customer.wishlist.price</name>
        </action>
        <action method="insert">
            <blockName>customer.wishlist.price</blockName>
            <after>customer.wishlist.qty</after>
        </action>
    </reference>
</wishlist_index_index>
```