# Layout update XML for CMS page

Tags: xml, magento

I have a CMS page and I'm trying to make changes via the layout update in Magento for this CMS page.

I was able to use `setTemplate` to change the template that the hierarchy menu used to build the list of links for this CMS page.

Now I want to move the block to be after the CMS wrapper block of the page.  I thought the after tag was what I wanted so I did this:

```
<reference name="hierarchy_menu" after="cms.wrapper">
    <action method="setTemplate"><name>cms/hierarchy/menu-artists.phtml</name></action>
</reference>
```

`cms.wrapper` and `hiearchy_menu` are both children of the `content` block.  What I'm doing isn't working.  I'm not really sure how to get the menu re-positioned like I need.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work thanks to the post located here: [change order of blocks via local.xml file in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410206/change-order-of-blocks-via-local-xml-file-in-magento/4411538#4411538)

the answer!!:

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>hierarchy_menu</alias></action>
    <action method="insert"><blockName>hierarchy_menu</blockName><siblingName></siblingName><after>1</after></action>
    <reference name="hierarchy_menu">
        <action method="setTemplate"><name>cms/hierarchy/menu-artists.phtml</name></action>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

note on this:  i did NOT do this via local.xml.  I still put this directly in as the layout update for the specific cms page.