# Change order blocks magento xml local.xml but only on smartphone resolution

Tags: xml, magento, responsive-design, magento-1.9

Hello guys i need change the order of the blocsk on magento 1.9 but only in mobile or smarthphone resolution not in desktop resoluion.

I have checked this [change order of blocks via local.xml file in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410206/change-order-of-blocks-via-local-xml-file-in-magento) and https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-blocks-order.html#gref

But change the order on all resolutions of the website and need only on smartphone version ¿ Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Solved by duplicate folder App/design/frontend/theme/mytheme/ to App/design/frontend/theme/mytheme_mobile/, edit the local on mobile foleder an in magento in system >cofigration > design Add exteption to theme iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

Comment: I would suggest you try and solve this with css or JavaScript instead. Flexbox is perfect for this if you don't need to support old browsers.